# В каком предложении «всё» является местоимением?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, местоимение

А. С приходом весны всё расцвело.
Б. Татьяна пишет, и всё Евгений на уме.
C. Становится всё интереснее жить.
D. Дождь всё идёт!
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfkQy.jpg)

Comment: A. Для иноязычных, изучающих русский язык предназначен другой сайт https://russian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Тут задание на местоимение а не для иноязычных

Comment: Вы не заметили я написала вопрос найти местоимение в каком варианте есть местоимение

Comment: _Lei Chen: Какое предложение является местоимением?_ === Lei Chen, вопрос надо было бы сформулировать примерно так: _В каком предложении «всё» является местоимением?_

Comment: А какой вопрос задать к слову всё тогда с вариант да

Comment: Какой вопрос? К примеру, такой: _**Что** расцвело?_

Comment: А как насчёт б варианта оно относится к какой части речи ?К нему какой вопрос можно задать ?

Comment: Татьяна пишет,и всё Евгений на уме.здест какой вопрос можно задать или это частица где нельзя задать вопрос.

Comment: Это частица....

Comment: А как насчёт этого предложения Дождь всё идёт.здесь какой вопрос это наречие или как ? становиться всё интереснее жить . здесь какой вопрос

Answer (score 2):

[**ВЕСЬ**](http://endic.ru/academic/Ves-44405.html) (МАС)
**1)** всего́, м.; вся, всей, ж.; **всё**, всего́, ср.; мн. все, всех; ***местоимение** определительное.*
**4.** в значении существительного, **всё**, всего́, ср. То, что есть, целиком, без исключения.
*На всё кидаешь ты косой, неверный взгляд. Подозревая всех, во всем ты видишь яд* (Пушкин. Послание цензору). *Всё его занимало, всё он взвешивал, всё учитывал* (Фурманов. Чапаев).

Правильный ответ: вариант **А** (местоимение в значении существительного).
*С приходом весны **всё*** (что сделало?) *расцвело.* [расцвело (что?) всё]

До июня почти неделя, а уж **всё расцвело** на диво, листва деревьев приобрела зрелый летний вид, и подберёзовики появились, давно отцвели яблони, отцветает сирень. [Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник (1967)]

**Всё расцвело и выросло** на целый месяц раньше, чем обычно ― солнце ведь круглые сутки! [А. С. Эфрон. Письма Б. Л. Пастернаку (1948-1959)]

P. S. Первоначальная шапка вопроса являлась неверной (*Какое предложение является местоимением?*), я ее поправила.
Предложение не может **быть** местоимением, но может **состоять** из местоимения. Например:
*— Что у нас имеется для приёма гостей?

— Всё.*

Comment: Я хотела знать про особо спрягаемые и разноспрягаемые глаголы.например слово подшить ,подбежать,подшить,согнать.

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/raznospryagaemye-glagoly.html.

Comment: Выдержать в изъявительном и повелительном да

Comment: А как можно узнать глагол может быть и в изъявительном и повелительном .слово выдержать,сказать,написать, вывести,колоть.я не так это поняла можете мне объяснить эти примеры